# Why does googlenet (inception) work well on the ImageNet dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, imagenet

Some people said that the reason that inception works well on the ImageNet dataset is that:the original images in the ImageNet dataset have different resolutions, and they are resized to the same size when they are used. So the inception which can deal with different resolutions is very suitable to the ImageNet. Whether this description is true? Can anyone give some more details explanations? I am really very confused to this. Thanks so much!

Comment: Does [this paper](https://learningcarrot.wordpress.com/tag/deep-learning/) help your understanding?

Comment: yes, this paper is very helpful! thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all, Deep Convolution Neural Nets , receive fix Input Image size(if by size,you mean,the number of pixels), so all images should be in the same size or dimension, this means same resolution. on the other hand if image resolution is high with a lot of details , result of **any network** gets better. Imagnet images are high resolution from fliker and resizing theme need no interpolation so resized image remain in a good shape.

**Second** , inception module main goal is dimension reduction, it means if we have 1X1 convolution, so coefficient in dimension calculation is ONE:

```
output_dim = (input_dim + 2 * pad_data[i] - kernel_extent) / stride_data[i] + 1;
```

Inception or in other word GoogLeNet, network is huge (more than 100 layer) and computationally impossible for many CPU's or even GPU's to go through all convolutions , so it need to reduce dimension.

You can use deeper AlexNet(with more layer) in Imagnet Data-set and i bet it will give you a good result but when you want to go deeper than 30 layer you should have a good strategy, like Inception.by the way , Imagnet data-set has over 5 million images (last time i checked), in the Deep nets `more image == more accuracy`